# Correct my sketch of a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $d\colon  \mathbb{R}^2 \times \mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^+_0$ with

$d(x,y) = \begin{cases} d_2(x,y)  \text{ if x and y are on the same line through the origin 0}\\ d_2(x,0) + d_2(y,0) \text{ else}\end{cases}$

where $d_2(x,y)$ denotes Euclidean distance. Sketch the ball:

$B_1(1/2,0) := \{x \in R^2 : d(x,(1/2,0)) < 1 \}$

Comment on result. Is $B_1(1/2,0)$ an open set? a convex set ?

What I think:

[Fig1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4R9HM.png)

Basically it is first quadrant of circle ${x^2+y^2<0.5} $ and points on x axis [0,1.5]. How to properly write it ?

Comment: Why the first quadrant?

Comment: isn't $R_0^+$ mean non-negative numbers ?

Comment: True, but your space is $\mathbb R^2$, not $\mathbb R_+^2$.

Comment: then is it going to be all points inside $x^2+y^2 <0.5$ ? I'm not 100% sure

Comment: Yes, only it is not 0.5. Also, don't forget the points on x axis which you correctly identified before.